# Css my custom buttons in Mathjax- CkEditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, mathjax

Where should i write the css to edit my buttons in Mathjax ckEditor? I have read the documentation but i can't find a way.

Where are html and css files stored?

My buttons were created in Mathjax.js with this code:

```
{
  id: 'button1',
  type: 'button',
  button: 'button1',
  label: 'button1',
}
```

[image]

Comment: You added it in your web page/site?

Comment: Use a proper tool (firebug) to inspect the html and css, and then edit your css file or html

Comment: @XahedKamal yeah i added it in my web page . I can how see the html i need but i don't know where it is. I can't edit it...

Comment: If you've it live, share the link

Answer (score 1):

I see you gave an ID (`button1`) to the button with a label (`button1`). You can apply CSS using the ID this way -

```
#button1{
     // Your css here
}
```

But, by default that button will have some CSS applied already. So if you want your CSS to override those CSS, you'll have to link your CSS file after the CSS file of Mathjax. Otherwise, you'll have to use `!important` to force override the CSS of the button.

Comment: i found a dialog.css but when i write my code there , nothing happens to the project. Otherwise if i create a new css file , where should i save it?

Comment: If you've the site live, share the link. Would be easy to help you.

Comment: I don't have it live, it's on localhost webserver behind a client and so on.

Comment: What you've inside <header></header>  ?

Comment: I don't know man... in which Html? I have an Html file which is called editor_template.html and doesn't have a header.
in <head></head> there are like 100 lines of code which call javascripts